# Grouping by combinations of functions and plotting results - best practice method?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Working with a movie set database and I have a merged DataFrame, dfn.head(1) example:

```
id  popularity  original_title  cast    director    overview    runtime genres  release_date    vote_count  vote_average    release_year    budget_adj  revenue_adj keywords_y
0   135397  33.0    Jurassic World  Chris Pratt|Bryce Dallas Howard|Irrfan Khan|Vi...   Colin Trevorrow Twenty-two years after the events of Jurassic ...   124 Action|Adventure|Science Fiction|Thriller   6/9/15  5562    6.0 2015    1.379999e+08    1.392446e+09    monster
```

Where I have each keyword broken out into a new row for each movie. So each keyword receives attribution for the original values like revenue, popularity, director, runtime, etc.

Starting to create some custom metrics stored this way:

```
# count most popular keywords
kw_counts = dfn.groupby('keywords_y').count()['id'].nlargest(50)

# count most profitable keywords
kw_rev = dfn.groupby('keywords_y').sum()['revenue_adj'].nlargest(50)

# average revenue per keyword
arpk = kw_rev / kw_counts
```

And now I'm trying to plot things like the total revenue for the top 50 keywords, or the average revenue per keyword for top 50 "grossing" keywords. My confusion / interest after reading through the matplot lib docs is if it makes more sense to plot using a combined method below:

```
dfn.groupby('keywords_y').sum()['revenue_adj'].nlargest(50).plot(kind='bar',x='keywords_y', y='revenue_adj');
```

[image]

or is there a simpler / best practice approach to storing these .sum().nlargest(). combos somewhere and then referencing them in a plot?

Comment: Please provide some sample data